# Can't activate more than 4 monitors at the same time

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

As the title states, im currently running a system with a Radeon 7850 eyefinity 6 (6 separate mini display ports).

To every port I have connected an active mini DP to HDMI converters. in each of those is a basic HDMI to DVI-D converter and then a monitor connected.

The pc is running windows 7, and every monitor gets picked up under resolution settings.

At most I can activate 4 of the monitors at any given time, when i try to activate the 5th monitor it comes up with this error:

["Unable to save display settings"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973782)

The card specifically comes with 6 ports, and since the 6 monitors are also picked up, I don't understand why I cant just extend the view to include all 6 monitors.

As for the 6 Monitors, they are not all the same model, can that create a problem? Im lost as to what is preventing me from extending on to the last 2 monitors.

Comment: Are you using the windows settings to configure your displays or are you using the one from ATI Control Panel? Believe it or not, but it makes a difference.

Comment: I have tryed through Windows and through Catalyst without any success. Also the Crimson rubbish is usless as hell.

Comment: Can you try them at a lower resolution than native?

Comment: Tryed that already. Is there a limit to how many active Monitors u can have in windows?